# How to make mobile menu responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I used W3Schools to code a sidenav overlay menu https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp with an accordion https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp. I am trying to figure out how to make it responsive, but I am having no luck.

I have tried using #menu to fix it but the entire menu disappears. I do not know if it is because I am not using ul or li for my links or not.

```
<header>
   <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a class="accordion" href="#">Design &#9663;</a>
      <div class="panel">
         <a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a>
         <a href="#">Web</a>
      </div>
      <a href="photography.html">Photography</a>
      <a href="branding.html">Branding</a>
      <a href="about.html">About | Contact</a>
   </div>
   <span class="opening" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fas fa-stream"></i></span>
</header>
```

```
.sidenav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 4rem;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    float: left;
}

.sidenav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 32px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: mr-eaves-xl-modern,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    color: #504E4E;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    font-style: italic;
}

.opening {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5rem;
    left: 5%;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: #504E4E;
    float: left;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.accordion {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 18px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    color: #504E4E;
}

.active .accordion:hover{
    font-style: italic;
}

.panel {
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: mr-eaves-xl-modern,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #504E4E;
}
```

I would like for it to be a horizontal menu when scaled to desktop.

Comment: To do that you would have to try [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp). Otherwise you could have a look at this [code from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp)

Comment: this one https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_matchmedia will help you. Just remove and add attibute to your ` <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">` when matches reached.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ul` and `li` shouldn't have an effect.

Use media queries to apply a new style that overwrites your current style when your screen is at a certain size.

To target all screens that have a width greater than or equal to 1024 pixels use `@media ( min-width: 1024px )`. To target screens with width less than or equal to 1024 pixels use `@media ( max-width: 1024px )`.

One reason your menu isn't displaying is because you've set the width to 0 in the `.sidenav` selector. Remove that line. To make the menu display full width on desktop you might add the following code to your CSS file:

```
@media ( min-width: 1000px ) {
    .sidenav {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    .sidenav > a {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

This will not display the accordion well; you may need to restructure your HTML. However this should get you started with media queries and using different styles at different screen sizes.